# Coredata returns duplicate values. Can anyone had the same issue?

Tags: core-data, swift3

Im using swift3. When fetching data from coredata, it returns duplicate values. Using software Datum, i understood that database only contains the original value.
    class DatabaseManager: NSObject {

```
fileprivate static let sharedManager: DatabaseManager = DatabaseManager()
class var shared: DatabaseManager {
    return sharedManager
}

/*Returns the ManagedObjectContext*/
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

fileprivate var completionHandler: ((_ completed: Bool)-> Void)? = nil


override init() {
    privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    if let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        managedObjectContext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext
        privateManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
    }
}

deinit {
   managedObjectContext = nil
    privateManagedObjectContext = nil
}
```

}

//Fetching data

```
func getItem()->[ListItem]{

    var objects = [ListItem]()
    var uniqueObjects:[ListItem] = [ListItem]()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: false)
    let request : NSFetchRequest<ShoppyListItem> = ShoppyListItem.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<ShoppyListItem>
    //let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"excludedIDContain = %@","New")
   // request.predicate = predicate
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
        if objects.count > 0 {
            objects.removeAll()
        }
        objects =  try managedObjectContext?.fetch(request) ?? []
        return objects


    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
    return objects
}
```

// objects =  try managedObjectContext?.fetch(request) ?? [] returns duplicated objects

Comment: Please include the code causing the issue in your question.

Comment: Core Data doesn't care if you save duplicate instances. If you save duplicates, it will return duplicates.

Comment: @TomHarrington database only contains 5 values. But when i fetch i get 7 or 8.

Comment: Can you describe (a) how you know there are only 5, and (b) where you se 7 or 8? Does the `objects` array have 7 or 8 entries, or do you see them somewhere else?

Comment: @TomHarrington using datum. Its a software. I get the sqlite file location from code. And i use findet to find the file.open it with datum.
Inside datum, only 5 data is there.
When saving there is only 5.
But when i call managedObjectContext.fetch(request), it returns 7.

Comment: Core Data doesn't return duplicates. Either the persistent store really has all 7, or it just has 5 and your count is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: @TomHarrington its not just the count, it has duplicate values.
It was due to concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it. Im not mistaken about the count. It was due to concurrency. i was not running fetch on the safe thread of coredata.  All i had to do was put the code inside perform block.
managedObjectContext.perform(block).
Got this from stanford ios tutorial named coredata demo. Video time 26:00. The professor explains this.